# Disable Zoom in Google Marker

Tags: javascript, zooming, qlikview

I've no idea about editing .js but we have a requirement where if a user clicks on a city (ex: New York) it should not drill down.
If I click a cluster it should zoom in but if I click a marker it should stay same. I've tried editing it but as I'm not proficient I couldn't make it work.
**Below is the .js script for extension**

```
function map_init() {

Qva.AddExtension('GoogleMaps - Cluster', function() {

    var _this = this;
    var divName = _this.Layout.ObjectId.replace("\\", "_");
    var popupLabels = _this.Layout.Text0.text;
    var gSize = _this.Layout.Text1.text;
    var mZoom = _this.Layout.Text2.text;
    var disableStyles = _this.Layout.Text3.text;
    var markers = [];
    var infoList = [];
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var styles = [{
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }, {
            "lightness": 65
        }, {
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }, {
            "lightness": 51
        }, {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }, {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }, {
            "lightness": 30
        }, {
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }, {
            "lightness": 40
        }, {
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }, {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }, {
            "lightness": -25
        }, {
            "saturation": -100
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "hue": "#ffff00"
        }, {
            "lightness": -25
        }, {
            "saturation": -97
        }]
    }]

    if (this.Element.children.length === 0) {
        var ui = document.createElement("div");
        ui.setAttribute("id", divName);
        this.Element.appendChild(ui);
        $("#" + divName).css("height", _this.GetHeight() + "px").css("width", _this.GetWidth() + "px");
    } else {
        $("#" + divName).css("height", _this.GetHeight() + "px").css("width", _this.GetWidth() + "px");
        $("#" + divName).empty();
    };


    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
        name: "Grayscale"
    });
    var mapOptions = {
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false
        },
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(divName), mapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);

    var reg = /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|bmp)$/;
    var rowreg = _this.Data.Rows[0];

    if (reg.test(rowreg[4].text)) {
        for (var i = 0, k = _this.Data.Rows.length; i < k; i++) {
            var row = _this.Data.Rows[i];
            var val = parseFloat(row[0].text);
            var val2 = parseFloat(row[1].text);
            console.log(val, val2)
            if (val != NaN && val != '' && val <= 90 && val >= -90 && val2 != NaN && val2 != '' && val2 <= 180 && val >= -180) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(val, val2);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    title: '',
                    icon: row[4].text,
                    customData: row[2].text
                });

                if (popupLabels === 1) {

                    marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: row[3].text
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                        infoList.push(this);
                        this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                        infoList.push(this);
                        this.infoWindow.close();
                    });
                };

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(lat, lng) {
                    return function() {
                        _this.Data.SearchColumn(0, lat, false);
                        _this.Data.SearchColumn(1, lng, true)
                    }
                })(val, val2));
                latlngbounds.extend(latLng);
                markers.push(marker);
            }
        };
    } else {

        for (var i = 0, k = _this.Data.Rows.length; i < k; i++) {
            var row = _this.Data.Rows[i];
            var val = parseFloat(row[0].text);
            var val2 = parseFloat(row[1].text);
            if (val != NaN && val != '' && val <= 90 && val >= -90 && val2 != NaN && val2 != '' && val2 <= 180 && val >= -180) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(val, val2);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    title: '',
                    customData: row[2].text
                });

                if (popupLabels === 1) {

                    marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: row[3].text
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                        infoList.push(this);
                        this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                        infoList.push(this);
                        this.infoWindow.close();
                    });
                };
            }
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(lat, lng) {
                return function() {
                    _this.Data.SearchColumn(0, lat, false);
                    _this.Data.SearchColumn(1, lng, true)
                }
            })(val, val2));
            latlngbounds.extend(latLng);
            markers.push(marker);
        };
    }

    //map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    if(disableStyles) {
        var clusterStyles = [{
            opt_textColor: 'black',
            url: Qva.Remote + '?public=only&name=Extensions/' + encodeURIComponent('GoogleMaps - Cluster') + '/singlecluster.png',
            height: 56,
            width: 55


    var mcOptions = {
        gridSize: gSize,
        styles: clusterStyles,
        maxZoom: mZoom
    };

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
    markerCluster.setCalculator(function(markers, clusterStyles) {

        var index = 0,
            count = markers.length,
            total = count;

        while (total !== 0) {
            //Create a new total by dividing by a set number
            total = parseInt(total / 5, 10);
            //Increase the index and move up to the next style
            index++;
        }
        index = Math.min(index, clusterStyles);

        var measure = 0;
        for (var i = 0, k = count; i < k; i++) {
            measure += parseInt(markers[i].customData)
        }
        var abbreviatedValue = abbreviateNumber(measure)
        return {
            text: abbreviatedValue,
            index: index
        };
    });

});
```

I do not how to set the zoom level. I tried zoomvalue as false but cluster is not zooming. I want markers to not zoom to street level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing the marker click listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(lat, lng) {
    return function() {
        _this.Data.SearchColumn(0, lat, false);
        _this.Data.SearchColumn(1, lng, true)
    }
})(val, val2));
```

Comment: I've tried removing that but it did not work. :( Thanks though.

Comment: bdiamante, you're my hero :p. It worked very well. I deleted that but then the above thing was 2 times in the script. And I only deleted once, it wasn't working. Now I deleted both and there is no more zoom. Thanks a lot.